# Convergence of $\int \cos(nx)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

How can we show $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_X\cos(nx) \rightarrow 0\;$?

(X can be any set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_X\cos nx\,dx=\left.\frac{1}{n}\sin nx\right|_X\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{} 0$$

as $\,\sin nx\,$ is bounded on $\,X\subset \Bbb R\,$ (why?)

Answer (score 1):

Begin by doing it for a closed bounded interval.  Then exploit the basic properties of limits.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Check Riemann–Lebesgue lemma.